# Oracle 12C: ORA-00406: COMPATIBLE parameter needs to be 12.2.0.0.0

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle12c, impdp, expdp

We have a 2 current Oracle 10G(10.2.0.1) production databases, and we are planning to migrate to a new database server with Oracle 12C. Since data is for each database is only around 5GB, the best way to create a new instance and use data pump to transfer data. To achieve this, I created a database link from the Oracle 12C database to the 10G, and use that to expdp the data from the 12C database. However when I import the exported data I have around tables that have an error like this:

```
ORA-39083: Object type TABLE:"USER"."WH_SEARCH_ACT" failed to create with error:
ORA-00406: COMPATIBLE parameter needs to be 12.2.0.0.0 or greater
ORA-00722: Feature "Partition Read Only"
```

Is there any solution to this other than adding the COMPATIBLE parameter in the production database? This is production so I can't really just update/modify the current production database. Any other solutions here, because i don't like just create the tables before importing the data pump file.

Answer (score 2):

Use the version parameter in the data pump utility. For example:

```
 expdp hr/hr TABLES=hr.employees VERSION=10.2 
DIRECTORY=data_pump_dir DUMPFILE=emp10g.dmp LOGFILE=emp.log
```

Just make sure the version of the export utility is 10g and import utility is 12G. Hope this helps.

Comment: I need to make the export from Oracle 10g and use Oracle 12c import ?

Comment: Still get the same error and another error as well `ORA-39083: Object type SEQUENCE:"USER"."PNR_RMRK_ACCT_LINE_SEQ" failed to create with error:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

Comment: It seems likely you are running into a bug. There are MOS notes on this topic, [such as this one](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/340300_1.html). If you have an Oracle Support contract then you should raise an SR. If you don't have a Support contract then re-run the export without the sequences and write a script to apply them manually.

Answer (score 0):

In the production database . you can use exp program

```
exp  username/password  buffer=64000 file=/path/to/path.dmp full=y
```

copy exp dump file to oracle 12c and use

```
imp  username/password  buffer=64000  file=/path/to/path.dmp full=y
```

Comment: May I ask why exp only not expdp ?

Comment: oracle 12c  imp program downward compatible   and  you can only create user . I think it 's easier

Comment: yes. you can  create user(schema) in the oracle 12c.  then  use imp  program import dumpfile